# loading non-default state of ui-router not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, route-provider

So i have two states, home state is by default, but when i first load my application using localhost:8080/myApplicatoin/#/resume, it still loads /home state, only after second attempt it loads home state,but i need to load resume state for some purpose without changing the default load state from home.

how can this be fixed

```
angular.module('wmApp.wmStates', [])

.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

  $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        template: '<h3>STATE SUCCESSFUL</h3>'
      })
      .state('resume', {
        url: '/resume',
        template: '<h3>{{ data }}</h3>',
        controller: 'ResumeCtrl'
      })
  ;

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
}])
.run(['$state', function($state) {
  console.log('Current State: ', $state.current);
}])
;
```

Comment: It would default to `/home` if you had the wrong path - maybe you're not hitting your state at the right url. Did you try hashbang instead? `#!/resume` ? https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: when i use #!/resume, it doesn't find my state, it says 404 not found